# Wpf WebBrowser suppressed script error but some scripts doesn't work properly

Tags: wpf

I have already disabled java script errors in wpf webbrowser control on after navigate event by following code.

```
public static void SetSilent(System.Windows.Controls.WebBrowser browser, bool silent)
        {
            if (browser == null)
                throw new ArgumentNullException("browser");
```

`// get an IWebBrowser2 from the document
        IOleServiceProvider sp = browser.Document as IOleServiceProvider;
        if (sp != null)
        {
            Guid IID_IWebBrowserApp = new Guid("0002DF05-0000-0000-C000-000000000046");
            Guid IID_IWebBrowser2 = new Guid("D30C1661-CDAF-11d0-8A3E-00C04FC9E26E");

            object webBrowser;
            sp.QueryService(ref IID_IWebBrowserApp, ref IID_IWebBrowser2, out webBrowser);
            if (webBrowser != null)
            {
                webBrowser.GetType().InvokeMember("Silent", BindingFlags.Instance | BindingFlags.Public | BindingFlags.PutDispProperty, null, webBrowser, new object[] { silent });
            }
        }
    }


    [ComImport, Guid("6D5140C1-7436-11CE-8034-00AA006009FA"), InterfaceType(ComInterfaceType.InterfaceIsIUnknown)]
    private interface IOleServiceProvider
    {
        [PreserveSig]
        int QueryService([In] ref Guid guidService, [In] ref Guid riid, [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.IDispatch)] out object ppvObject);
    }`

But some java scripts doesn't work properly and not get any error take no affect. Also future emulation mode is correct on registry.

Thank You.

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution for it. After navigate complete event does not work properly or state is not ready. Have to check first.

```
var browser = webBrowser1;
```

`if (browser == null || browser.Document == null)
            return;

        dynamic document = browser.Document;

        if (document.readyState != "complete")
            return;

        SetSilent(webBrowser1, true);`